# Auto-sized grid rows doing weird sizing when item with RowSpan spans the row

Tags: wpf

So I basically have the following code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row0"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Row1"/>

    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1">
        <!-- Some stuff here in the GroupBox -->
    </GroupBox>

    <!-- Some other stuff in Grid.Row="3" -->
</Grid>
```

What's happening is that the first two rows are not sizing correctly to the TextBlocks within them, their size is being affected by the GroupBox.  I added the 3rd row essentially to just provide spill-over room since the GroupBox is a little taller than the first two rows together, but this is making the first two rows increase in size as well, similar to what I would expect if they were star-sized.  If I comment out the GroupBox, the first two rows size correctly to their respective TextBlocks.  Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to make it do what I think it should?

Answer (score 1):

Try this setup for your rows:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Won't that make the GroupBox then spill over into the 4th row?  I still want the 4th row to be fully below the GroupBox.

Comment: I don't think so no. I put a quick sample together and the above markup seemed to achieve the layout you want. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Hmm you're right, but I don't understand why that works.  If the row is given a height of 0 shouldn't it always have a height of 0, rather than expanding to fit the content a la Auto?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why it works either, I was just experimenting. If I get a chance I'll have a dig around to see if the behaviour is documented

Comment: Gary, I took away your accepted answer because it has some unintended consequences.  At first glance it appeared to do what I wanted, however the problem is that the star-sized row doesn't just squish a bit from the top, the entire thing remains the same size but actually gets shifted down by the amount that the control spills over into the zero-sized row.  So if the control spilled 50 pixels down into the zero-sized row, the bottom 50 pixels of the star-sized row are not visible at all.  Just didn't want anyone looking at this in the future to be confused.

Comment: Ah ok, no problem. Did you find a solution? If not I might have to have another look!

Comment: I did not find a solution to do it with a single Grid, but I worked around it another way by taking the GroupBox out of the Grid with the TextBlocks and wrapping everything in an outer Grid.  I just posted what I did as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing since I couldn't get this to work in a single Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Row0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Row1"/>
    </Grid>

    <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- Stuff in the GroupBox -->
    </GroupBox>

    <!-- Stuff in Grid.Row="1" -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it can be done with a single grid. You could switch your inner grid for a `StackPanel` if you like, then when you add additional rows you don't need to update the `RowDefinitions`